# Android: Connect app to NAS server

Tags: android, nas

I would like connect the app I've developed to an own made NAS server (not from the market) for database service. I would like to have sign up&login function, newsfeed and upload images/videos from app to NAS and vice versa. Is it possible to connect NAS with android studio apps?i could not find any proper references/findings regarding this. Can someone suggest some tutorials for thorough learning. Any help/guidance is much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: You would need e.g. a webserver running on your NAS. Whether that is possible depends on the model.

Comment: So i need a webserver in order to connect it to the mobile app?how do we do that?sorry im relatively new to this..so how to do the connection(coding) for android studio?is there any proper tutorials for that?@mlidal